# Firebase is doubling data

Tags: swift, database, firebase, authentication

The problem I have is the following, when I log in a user and insert data into the database everything works fine, but when I close section and start section again the data is doubled without having inserted anything. What is the cause of that?

login metho

```
@IBAction func loginButton(_ sender: Any) {

    if validar() {

        try! FIRAuth.auth()!.signOut()
        FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(withEmail: emailTextField.text!, password: passwordTextField.text!, completion: { (user, error) in

            if user != nil {

                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "loginToPasswordBag", sender: self)

            } else {

                self.emailTextField.shake()
                self.passwordTextField.shake()
            }
        })

    }
}
```

Save data method

```
@IBAction func addPassword(_ sender: Any) {

    FIRAuth.auth()?.addStateDidChangeListener({ (auth, user) in

        if let user = user {

            var password = [String:String]()
            password["password"] = self.passwordTextField.text!
            password["name"] = self.namePasswordTextField.text!
            password["uid"] = user.uid
            self.rootRef.child("passwords").childByAutoId().setValue(password)

        }
    })

}
```

When I log in again the last inserted object is duplicated in the database

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. But it is expected behavior that `addStateDidChangeListener` fires when you restart the app. It may also periodically fire while the app is running. So you should not depend on logic that `addStateDidChangeListener` will only fire when you call `signInWithEmail`.

Comment: Ohh I think you're right, I thought, that if a view changes, the handlers will no longer fire

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is expected behavior that `addStateDidChangeListener` fires when you restart the app. It may also periodically fire while the app is running.

So you should not depend on logic that `addStateDidChangeListener` will only fire when you call `signInWithEmail`.